# Как сделать так,что бы margin не влиял на общую длину контейнера?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я пытаюсь сделать слайд-меню на css. Каждый раз при прокрутке с помощью

```
margin: -10%;
```

Все элементы внутри блока растягиваются,так как вместе с добавлением margin изменяется длина контейнера. Как я понял, это можно изменить с помощью box-sizing, но он никак не повлиял на поведение контейнера в моем случае. Что еще можно сделать что бы контейнер перестал изменять длину в зависимости от margin?

```css
.slide_menu {
    background-image: url('../img/our_projects-bg.png');
    height: 500px;
}
.slide {
    display: flex;
    width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.image {
  max-width: 300%;
  min-width: 300%;
  font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: flex;
margin-left: 0;
transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);


height: 500px;

}
.image article {
     max-width: 8%;
     min-width: 8%;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-left: 47px;
}
.image article * {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
   }
   .image article img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: auto:;
    flex-basis: auto;
   }



.image article:nth-child(1n) .top {
  background-color: #02B4B5;
  height: 300px;
 }
.image article:nth-child(2n) .top{
 background-color: #D05E24;
 height: 300px;
}
.image article:nth-child(3n) .top {
 background-color: #03689E;
 height: 300px;
}

.image article:nth-child(1n) .bottom {
  background-color: #009091;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
 }
.image article:nth-child(2n) .bottom{
 background-color: #C94705;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.image article:nth-child(3n) .bottom {
 background-color: #005E91;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
.left_arr {
    padding: 15px;
    border:3px solid black;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left:1%;
}
.right_arr {
    right: 1%;
    padding: 15px;
    border:3px solid black;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.left_arr,
.right_arr
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;

}
.bottom a {
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 60%;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="image">
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_boy.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Интерактивная сеть организаций и проектов</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_map.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Социальный технопарк "Долина семьи и детства"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_dad.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Гала концерт Фестиваля семейного творчества "успешкая семья"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_boy.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Интерактивная сеть организаций и проектов</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_map.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Социальный технопарк "Долина семьи и детства"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_dad.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Гала концерт Фестиваля семейного творчества "успешкая семья"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_boy.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Интерактивная сеть организаций и проектов</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_map.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Социальный технопарк "Долина семьи и детства"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <div class="top">
                            <img src="img/slide_dad.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <span>Гала концерт Фестиваля семейного творчества "успешкая семья"</span>
                            <a href>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: добавьте больше кода

Comment: @meine Добавил, но кнопки еще не доделаны. margin для теста я добавляю вручную

Comment: какой результат вы хотите получить?